# Create a column with either Var1 or Var2

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two variables : date1 and date2. I'd like to create a third column that displays the latest date.

I tried this :

First I create the third variable

```
df$Column3 <-"2011-11-10"
```

Then I define how to pick the value :

```
df$Column3  <-  for (i in seq(1, 10))
  {df[i,]$Column3 <-max(c(df[i,]$Date1,df[i,]$Date2))
}
```

It doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look on `pmax()`. If you want DIY: `df$Column3 <- with(df, ifelse(Date1>Date2, Date1, Date2))`

Comment: Following the suggestion of @jogo, `pmax` is probably the easiest way to go: `df$Column3 <- pmax(df$Date1, df$Date2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to convert your Date1 and Date2 columns into date format, otherwise R just reads them as regular characters:

```
df <- data.frame(Date1 = c("2011-11-10", "2012-10-23", "2009-09-09"), 
             Date2 = c("2002-07-06", "2014-10-13", "2001-08-07"))

df$Date1 <- as.Date(df$Date1)
df$Date2 <- as.Date(df$Date2)
```

Then you can take the max using an apply function:

```
df$LatestDate <- apply(df[,1:2], 1, max)
df


     Date1      Date2  LatestDate
1 2011-11-10 2002-07-06 2011-11-10
2 2012-10-23 2014-10-13 2014-10-13
3 2009-09-09 2001-08-07 2009-09-09
```

Answer (score 1):

Better with reproducible data. Otherwise it's possible an answer is way off.

Anyway, if understand correctly, you want col3 to be the later date. I'm using `dplyr` from `tidyverse` and `lubridate` here.

Some data:

```
Column1 <- ymd(c("2011-11-09", "2011-11-10", "2011-11-12"))
Column2 <- ymd(c("2011-11-10", "2011-11-10", "2011-11-11"))
df <- data.frame(Column1, Column2)

# Add 3rd column
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- df %>% 
    mutate(Column3 = if_else(Column2>Column1, Column2, Column1))
```

and the 3rd column should be the later of the two:

```
     Column1    Column2    Column3
  2011-11-09 2011-11-10 2011-11-10
  2011-11-10 2011-11-10 2011-11-10
  2011-11-12 2011-11-11 2011-11-12
```